# How to replace dashes with forward slash using sed?

Tags: sed

I am using the date function to get the date in this format

`date +"%m-%d-%Y"` which returns `04-25-2022`. How can i replace the dashes so date is returned as `04/25/2022`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `sed`.  Just change the format that gets passed to `date`.

```
date +"%m/%d/%Y"
```

Comment: Accepted. I was doing date -d +"%m/%d/%Y", all i had to do was not use the d flag. Thank you.